# POST CORS request to HTTPS domain running sailsjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx, cors, sails.js

I got caught in problems with CORS and HTTPS and POST request and just cannot get out of it.

My setup:

- I have a web app that runs on HTTPS protocol
- I need to make POST request to API on different domain (sailsjs with CORS enabled)
- The API is setup to accept both HTTP and HTTPS requests (nginx)

Problems:

- On desktop everything works fine if I use HTTPS protocol. If I make call to HTTP, I get error: **"Blocked loading mixed active content"**
- On Mobile I spent days and days trying to make work HTTPS calls, I tried hundereds of ways, to no success. HTTP calls work fine, but again cannot use HTTPS to HTTP.

So basically, on desktop everything works splendid while everything is on https. On mobile it doesn't work. When switching to http target everything brakes because of mixed origin.

**More Details**

The webapp is using Angular which is making CORS POST HTTPS requests without any problems on all platforms.

The small part that I am trying to make work is using vanilla xhr request:

```
submit: function(data){
        var request = this.createCORSRequest("POST",'https://heregoesthedomain.com');

        if (request){
            request.onload = function() {
                // Success code goes here.
                console.log('success');
            };

            request.onerror = function() {
                // Error code goes here.
                console.log('error');
            };

            request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    },

    createCORSRequest: function(method, url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            // Most browsers.
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
            // IE8 & IE9
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            // CORS not supported.
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }
```

Angular seems to be making post requests from HTTPS to HTTPS from domain to domain without a problem across all platforms, while I just cannot seem to make it work in clean JS. I cannot use Angular script, because I need these calls to happen before Angular is initialized.

**Update 1**

Just to make clear, I didn't post this question after 5 minutes of trying. I have done all kinds of debugging, I have used remote consoles for mobile browser debugging etc etc.

If you ask for the error messages, there simply isn't any. Request returns status:0 and all other XMLHttp values are simply empty. I have read in one of the specs that request get sometime blocked when its been made from origin that is no longer active/doesnt exist, but that is not my case. Simply staying on the same static page.

Comment: "can't make it work" is rather vague. Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect? Compare the request you are making now with the one you were making with Angular. What is different about them?

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry I guess I didn't stress enough how much time and effort I already wasted on this. Everyting that you have mentioned I have done of course thousand ties and still doing. Analyzing errors, remote consoles for mobile browsers, etc etc tried everything - no success.

Comment: As I'm aware of you always going to get this error when doing from https to http. This why for example Netflix is playing movies in http but in back doing calls to https.

Comment: Any specific reason why you are trying to make this particular request using “vanilla” JavaScript, instead of relying on the methods angular has built-in for this?

Comment: @Tom are you using routing in angular ? Could it be that angular routing changes the url state (*while your ajax calls are running*) and that gets treated as the origin not being active anymore ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli As I said in the update, I read about that this could happen, so I made sure I am staying at static page and no its still doesn't work. By the way, from specs its more about if you totally change origin, eg. change domain or close the window, rather than just changing route. And still, angular http works... :(

Comment: @Tom, angular can change the url while you are staying in the same page through the history API. And that might throw off ajax calls still being retrieved (*as per the docs you read*) (***can you disclose the url of the webapp ?***)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes I know, but I did setup the page the way that doesn't happen and I cna be sure nothing is changing. And there is still what bugs me the most - angular's http still can do it, why cannot I do it with normal JS? Sorry at the moment cannot disclose, its all under auth anyway would be too complicated to setup

Answer (score -1):

Since you API works with both types of schemes you could make the requesting URL match the scheme of the page (*using a schema less url*)

```
this.createCORSRequest("POST",'//heregoesthedomain.com')
```

This should solve the

> Blocked loading mixed active content

problem.

Comment: That will just use HTTPS when the site is served via HTTPS – and if HTTPS CORS requests don’t work for some as of yet undetermined reason, nothing is won here.

Comment: @cbroe both stated problems mention https to http failures, so i thought to address that first and see if it fixes the problems.

Comment: He _needs_ to make his request via HTTPS (because of mixed content blockage), and _that_ is what doesn’t work on mobile. Whether or not he uses HTTPS “explicitly” by prefixing the address with `https://` or “implicitly” by using just `//` will likely not make any difference whatsoever.

Answer (score -2):

Also on IE8/IE9 you cannot do normal way any CORS request. You can sort it by using [XDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain)

Never then less still I will say that for web browser you will get problem with mix content. Only solution is creating special route so you will have http and other calls on https. 
If you have Netflix look that they sort it out by playing movie on http because there movie chunks are get by http and session is done by https

Comment: Sorry, don't see how this is helpful.. I do use xdomain for old IE browsers but that is irrelevant. I am also aware of the way Netflix does it but again irrelevant. I don't see point setting up prox for one single endpoint where I just dump some data - especially when I see that IT IS possible (angular), just fail to see why I cannot make it work

Comment: If you see it possible that ok . On my experience on huge angular project with 3800 unit tests we sort it like this. Every browser was doing same  "Blocked loading mixed active content" but some where only putting this in console log other where blocking stuff.